# L2 norm of composition of two functions

Tags: functions, lebesgue-integral, normed-spaces

Consider a function $f(x)$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$. Let $g_a(x)$ be defined as
\begin{equation}
    g_a(x) = \sinh ((\text{arsinh}\;x) - a)
\end{equation}
for some real number $a$.

Now let us consider composition $f \circ g_a$. I would like to know whether $f \circ g_a= f(\sinh ((\text{arsinh}\;x) - a))$ is still in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

Clearly, if $a=0$, then $\Vert f \circ g_0 \Vert_{L^2} = \Vert f \Vert_{L^2}$. What happens when $a \neq 0$?

Any help is deeply acknowledged.

Comment: Do you mean  $\sinh ((\text{arsinh}\;x) - a)$ or $\sinh (\text{arsinh}(x - a))$?

Comment: @Paul Sinclair It is $\sinh((\text{arsinh}\;x)-a)$.

Comment: Then $$\begin{align}g_a(x) = \sinh((\text{arsinh}\;x) - a) &= \sinh(\text{arsinh}\;x)\cosh a - \cosh(\text{arsinh}\;x)\sinh a\\
&= x\cosh a - \sqrt{1 + x^2}\sinh a\end{align}$$ which is a quite well behaved function. In particular, it is $C^\infty$, and strictly increasing for all $a$. And its derivative is bounded.  From this it will follow that $f\circ g_a$ is $L^2$.